# xcode 7.2 instead of 7.3 on mac 10.11.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I have udate the xcode to 7.3 from app store and app store say its xcode 7.3 but when open about the xcode its show version xcode 7.2.1. I am facing problem from days. I am unable to install build on my Iphone which has latest IOS 9.3.1 Please help.

Thanks

Comment: If your app is using Swift, you might have to update some code. Xcode includes Swift 2.2, which has some changes in the syntax compared to Swift 2.1 (is it is included in Xcode 7.2.x)

Here is a list of changes in Swift 2.2: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift2-2

Comment: Reboot. Reinstall...

Answer (score 0):

How do you launch Xcode? If form the dock - it's possible that you're launching old version installed manualy some time ago. Right-click on Xcode's icon and select options->show in Finder. I guess that you will see Xcode in location other that your Applications' folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys 
I have download the xcode 7.3 from apple developer downloads and install now 7.3 x